# Can't simulate Postman request in Java

Tags: java, postman, okhttp

I'm trying to login to a portal. It works using Postman. When I try the same request using plain Java or OkHttp the login fails and I will be redirected to the login page.

```
    HttpUrl.Builder httpBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://test58.cashctrl.com/auth/login.html").newBuilder();
    httpBuilder.addQueryParameter("JMCF_AUTH_EMAIL", "email");
    httpBuilder.addQueryParameter("JMCF_AUTH_PASSWORD", "password");

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(httpBuilder.build())
            .get()
            .build();
```

I know the Url looks weird but it works this way using Postman or even simply use a browser.

Alternative with plain Java, which I tried:

```
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put(PARAM_EMAIL, EMAIL);
    parameters.put(PARAM_PASSWORD, PASSWORD);


    URL url = new URL(LOGIN_URL + "?" + ParameterStringBuilder.getParamsString(parameters));
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);


    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    out.writeBytes(ParameterStringBuilder.getParamsString(parameters));
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    int status = con.getResponseCode();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.append(inputLine + "\n");
    }
    in.close();

    con.disconnect();
    System.out.println(status);
    System.out.println(content.toString());
```

Postman must be doing something special or also a browser which I don't see.

Comment: please try adding `Content-Type` to `HttpURLConnection con` object

Comment: That did't make a difference

Comment: any logs can you post on ?

Comment: First example is a GET second a POST. What is Postman doing ?

Comment: In Postman both Get and Post work. Well there are no logs just a response, in postman I get the response from the portal, in Java I get the login page again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I got to know that Postman has "code" feature. Below the send button you can see the code option it will generate the code for you. There is a list of language to choose from and java is one of them. Do check that out. Also you must be missing the cookie, see the temporary headers in Postman add all in your code and do include the cookie one.

Thanks I hope it helps.

Comment: Good comment, not a good answer. This doesn't explain the problem with the current code.

Comment: I was going to comment but didn't had enough reputation :)
Now I can owing to this upvote.